# Return deleted project from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have serious problem, I have deleted Java project from Eclipse and I don't have fresh revision on CVS. Is there any chance anyway to return that project or I am najebao ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete the project from the Eclipse workspace only? Or from the disk? (this option between the two deletions is proposed when removing a project).

- If it is from the workspace, you can re-import the project.
- If it is from the disk, it is gone (unless some kind of ["undelete" tool](https://superuser.com/questions/128786/need-decent-undelete-utility-for-windows) can get back those files)